# Firebase Realtime Database not saving data when I add "location.replace"

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to push data to Firebase Real-time Database and after the data is pushed(and saved), the browser should open another page. I have used "location.replace()" function to open the next page however adding the *location.replace* line makes the data not to be saved in Firebase real-time database.

Here is my code

```
var updates = {};
updates['/users/' + document.getElementById('username').value] = data;
firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
console.log("Saved successfully")
location.replace("nextpage.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

The `update` function is asyncronous; it will take some time to complete. If you want to wait until the update is done, then you will need to use the promise it returns:

```
var updates = {};
updates['/users/' + document.getElementById('username').value] = data;
firebase.database().ref().update(updates)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Saved successfully');
    location.replace('nextpage.html');
  });
```

Or with `async`/`await`:

```
async function someFunction () {
  var updates = {};
  updates['/users/' + document.getElementById('username').value] = data;
  await firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
  console.log("Saved successfully")
  location.replace("nextpage.html");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the update seems to be asynchronous function, returning a promise.
so you should properly handle it. Otherwise call to "location" may come before the update is finished.

Change it like this:

```
firebase.database().ref().update(updates).then(() => {
  console.log("Saved successfully")
  location.replace("nextpage.html");
}).catch(error => {console.log('Error:', error)})
```

If you don't want to use promise, provide an additional argument to the update function that will serve as a callback function, i.e will be called when update is finished:

```
firebase.database().ref().update(updates, function() {
  console.log("Saved successfully")
  location.replace("nextpage.html");
})
```